# same login for different subdomain in YII2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to handle login in such case that, my frontend is on root of website i.e, http://www.example.com and backend in on subdomain http://admin.example.com. If i loggedin to root or in backend, it will automatically loggedin to other.

Goal: Login to both sites when logged in to one.

Comment: Do you want to login to both sites when logged in to one or do you want to log in to them separately?

Comment: What do you meant by cookies session ?... login information should verify through session.

Comment: @topher, Yes, login to both sites when logged in to one...

Comment: is it 2 different applications?

Answer (score 3):

Try [this method](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/cookies.md#cross-subdomain-authentication-and-identity-cookies). I think this is what you looking for.

Comment: While this ended up working for me, simply posting a link is not considered a constructive answer. Try explaining the code you've linked to.

Answer (score 0):

> use session to store the id and use its data to login into other subdomain(s)

```
$session = new Session;$session->open();$value1 = $session['name1'];  // get session variable 'name1'
```

[read about session here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html)

Comment: While writing the function for logoff don't forget to destroy the session

Comment: My question is how to get/handle the session in different domain, in same time.

Comment: do study the behavior of session, first. Scope of Session is restricted to the domain.

Comment: @AbdulAhad You can store your session in database as well as session id in cookie of browser. when any of your application will load it will check for cookie first then get the session id from there and verify that id in your database. If its found you can use corresponding session id's value for your appilcation.

Comment: @AbdulAhad PHP session ids are saved in Cookies. To make a cookie available in all the sub-domains you need to assign it to the root domain. Then all the sub-domains will get the session id from cookie and PHP can find the session using passed session id.

As it turns out, You just need to set the session.cookie_domain to the root domain in php.ini file

`session.cookie_domain = ".example.com" `
check this documentation [link] (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/135/single-sign-on-across-multiple-subdomains/)